# Unable to Upload Simulator Build for App Review to Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am trying to upload instagram iOS for review to get certain permissions but there is no way to upload simulator build to instagram.
There is an option to upload Simulator Build but when i tapped it it does nothing. I have tried to do this with different browsers but with no success.
I have done this last year with another application but this time Button does nothing.[image]

Comment: What does the Developer Console of your browser tell?

Comment: @Raptor it tells nothing. Nothing happens when i tap this button. Thats weird and i have tried to create a new application with all other data uploaded but again got stuck there. There is no error or anything. On tapping this button, nothing happens. Usually it opens the file browser where we can select apk/zip file to upload.

Comment: Made a contact to and reported the problem yesterday but so far unable to get any response. Now i've created a bug on Facebook developers too https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1782385408599828/